# Extract possible `null` value from JSON string and put in tuple for unzip later

Tags: json, scala

I have couple of questions on handling possible `null` value in JSON string in Scala and having `None` value for `unzip` operation.

I have field in JSON string which can have value or can be `null`. I need to handle both in Scala code so I am writing plain `if(null)` check. Is there efficient way to do in Scala?

```
def collectSecondId(value: SomeJsonObject) = {
  if(value.someField == null) {
    None
  } else {
    Some(value.someField.id)
  }
```

Secondly these values will be in packed in some list of tuples. Which in turn can have `None` if I returned as above. So is there a way to return other than `None` if returning `None` is not a good idea.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your method using `Try`:

```
def collectSecondId(value: SomeJsonObject) =
    Try(value.someField.id).toOption
```

If `value.someField` is null, your Try will result in a Failure which will then manifest as a None.

Answer (score 0):

```
for {
  optValue <- Option(value) // Evaluates to None if value is null
  someField <- Option(optValue.somefield) // Evaluates to None if somefield is null
  id <- Option(someField.id) // Evaluates to None if id is null
} yield value
```

This will result in None if any of the values are null, or Some(id) if they're all defined. Though - rather than doing this manually, you might be better off using a JSON parsing library like Argonaut.